# Subset iterator for Arrays/Lists in C# without yield

Tags: c#, c++, performance

A class that stores an `std::vector<int>` internally can easily expose subset iterators using the subset indices as follows:

begin:

```
return _data.begin() + _subset_begin;
```

end:

```
return _data.begin() + _subset_end;
```

Is there an efficient way to do this in C#? My initial implementation based on yield was very slow.

```
for(int i = _subset_begin; i < _subset_end; ++i)
{
    yield return _data[i];
}
```

How do I solve this problem efficiently?

I am aware that it's not quite the same, as C++ uses iterators as return types while C# uses IEnum instead; but these are the conventions for each language...

Comment: Is the iterator exposed by [ArraySegment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hsbd92d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) more performant? Also: Were you testing a RELEASE build run outside the debugger?

Comment: ArraySegment is the solution. Make an answer out of it and I will accept it.

Comment: I composed a somewhat more detailed answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Linq, it actually makes very little difference whether you use a raw array or a wrapped one.

To test this, I wrote the following program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

namespace Demo
{
    public static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            var sw = new Stopwatch();

            int[] array = new int[1000000];

            int loops = 100;

            for (int trial = 0; trial < 4; ++trial)
            {
                sw.Restart();

                for (int i = 0; i < loops; ++i)
                    subsetViaArraySegment(array, 0, array.Length).Sum();

                Console.WriteLine("subsetViaArraySegment() took " + sw.Elapsed);
                sw.Restart();

                for (int i = 0; i < loops; ++i)
                    subsetViaYield(array, 0, array.Length).Sum();

                Console.WriteLine("subsetViaYield() took " + sw.Elapsed);
                sw.Restart();

                for (int i = 0; i < loops; ++i)
                    array.Sum();

                Console.WriteLine("Simple Sum() took " + sw.Elapsed);
                sw.Restart();

                for (int i = 0; i < loops; ++i)
                {
                    int total = 0;

                    for (int j = 0, n = array.Length; j < n; ++j)
                    {
                        unchecked
                        {
                            total += array[j];
                        }
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Inline code took " + sw.Elapsed);
                Console.WriteLine("");
            }
        }

        private static IEnumerable<int> subsetViaYield(int[] source, int start, int count)
        {
            for (int i = start, n = start + count; i < n; ++i)
                yield return source[i];
        }

        private static IEnumerable<int> subsetViaArraySegment(int[] source, int start, int count)
        {
            return new ArraySegment<int>(source, start, count);
        }
    }
}
```

It tests how long it takes to using Linq to sum all the integers in a large array using `ArraySegment`, a yield implementation, and just the raw array itself. It also does an inline calculation without using Linq at all.

The results for an x64 RELEASE build run on Windows 8.1 are as follows:

```
subsetViaArraySegment() took 00:00:00.6924651
subsetViaYield() took 00:00:00.9207855
Simple Sum() took 00:00:00.9876048
Inline code took 00:00:00.0884620

subsetViaArraySegment() took 00:00:01.0222854
subsetViaYield() took 00:00:00.9309415
Simple Sum() took 00:00:01.0031804
Inline code took 00:00:00.0890534

subsetViaArraySegment() took 00:00:01.0146586
subsetViaYield() took 00:00:00.9129277
Simple Sum() took 00:00:00.9842326
Inline code took 00:00:00.0890593

subsetViaArraySegment() took 00:00:01.0306027
subsetViaYield() took 00:00:00.9353762
Simple Sum() took 00:00:00.9902355
Inline code took 00:00:00.0879321
```

Note how the Linq approaches all take a similar amount of time - and the inline code is MANY times faster.

Therefore if you really need the fastest code possible, you should not use Linq. Instead you could use `ArraySegment` to wrap the array, and then write code that uses the subset defined by the array segment.

For example, a function to calculate the sum of an integer array segment could look like this:

```
public static long Sum(ArraySegment<int> arraySegment)
{
    long total = 0;
    var array = arraySegment.Array;

    for (int i = arraySegment.Offset, n = i + arraySegment.Count; i < n; ++i)
        total += array[i];

    return total;
}
```